# If every element of $R$ not in $M$ is a unit, then $R/M$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

> True/False Test:
> [image]

The answer says it to be true. But can't I consider $M$ to be $R$ by default (for then it would comes out to be false)?

Please help

Comment: Strictly speaking this is wrong when $M=R$, but otherwise true.

Comment: So what should be the correct choice (T/F)?

Comment: If they use the definition of field that is the same as the one on Wikipedia, then strictly speaking it is false.

Comment: This is the reason why the T/F-questions in my exams REQUIRE either a brief justification or a counterexample. I would then be well placed in grading this question accepting either the counterexample $M=R$ or the justification in the case the student understood my intention to only consider proper ideals :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unit in $R$ will remain a unit in $R/M$. The assumption thus shows that every non-zero element in $R/M$ is a unit. Hence, if the ideal $M$ was proper, this shows that $R/M$ is a field.

Comment: But the question didn't use the term _proper_ for $M.$

Comment: If $R=M$ then $R/M$ is the zero-ring which is not a field.

Comment: That's what OP was saying all along, by the way.

Comment: Not all along actually. It was added within the five minute window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct! Perhaps the definition of field used on the exam did not include the axiom $1 \neq 0$. In that case, $\langle 0 \rangle$ is a field. But I think that definition makes stating theorems more cumbersome, because we are constantly having to say, "Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a *nonzero* field..."